# How to start other script inside a running python script(A new thread or process?)

Tags: python, multithreading

If I have a program like this:

```
for i in range (25000):
    do something
    if i == 5000:
        run  new_script.py in a new thread/process
    continue as before
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Hello, welcome to StackOverflow! If you already haven't, please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). What have you tried until this point ?

Comment: The `if` syntax does not use parentheses and use double `=` signs for comparison

Comment: Why do you want to use a *thread* to execute a different script when the standard way is to use a new process? A thread has to share the code and static data, which will require that you import the other script into your current process, while a new process will live its life independantly.

Comment: @SergeBallesta: I edited my question. If you think process is a better solution please give me some codes to do that. Thanks.

Comment: @I changed the code from `Thread` to `Process` and seems there is no errors, but the second program doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Put the content of new_script.py in a function and import it

```py
from threading import Thread

from new_script import f

for i in range (25000):
    do_something()
    if i == 5000:
        Thread(target=f, args=(arg1, arg2)).start()
```

Comment: Thanks Politinsa, I tried your code but got this error message: `Exception in thread Thread-8:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\threading.py", line 917, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\threading.py", line 865, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
TypeError: f() takes 1 positional argument but 10 were given`

Comment: `args` is a tuple containing the argument that will be passed to your `f` function. Check the signature of `f` and adapt `args=(arg1, arg2)`

Comment: I used a code like this `Thread(target=f, args=(z)).start()
`

Comment: I edited my question. please read.